# How do I clear out some information recorded in Google accounts?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have a phone that is running Android. I have several Gmail accounts setup on the phone, many of which belong to my family members who are computer illiterate while a couple of the accounts are my own.

The only reason I have those accounts on my phone is to teach my family how to use email on their phones, which I am going to get them shortly.

Today I noticed for the first time that every one of those Gmail accounts record my mobile device under the "Android device" section of the dashboard. Every Gmail account has the rest of the accounts recorded. The market info too is common to all. Furthermore, they all show the same IMEI. That is plain wrong.

I tried removing all the accounts except my own from my phone but the information recorded still persists. Is it going to be updated after some time when the server cache is cleared? If not, how can I correct this?

Comment: Just to verify you have removed the accounts from your phone right?  The only way I know to get rid of persona information collected by Google is to delete the account.  This would be true for Apple's iCloud service and Microsoft's Hotmail service.

Comment: Yes, I have removed all the accounts from my phone. What you say is extreme and not acceptable at all. Why do these companies make it so hard. Bollocks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to delete this info. I have accounts that were added and deleted from my device more than 2 years ago but the controll panel still lists my device.